# AngularJS navigation by HTTP status code. (MVC design)

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, navigation, http-status-code-404

I’m trying the convert an unstructured jQuery application to MVC AngularJS but at one point I’m kind of lost or I just don’t get it… (Unfortunately I’m not a JavaScript-God so the error might also be there)

This is the snippet of the original jQuery code.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",  
    url: "rest/users/" + userId + "/requests",  
                accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                statusCode: {
                    200: function(data) {               
                        // do something
                    },
                    404: function() {
                        window.location = 'index.html';
                    },
                    500: function() {
                        alert("Server Error!");
                    }
                }                   
            });
```

A simple REST call where the HTTP response code is used to navigate. Unfortunately I can’t make this run in AnglularJS.

Here is my Controller:

```
// Inside the RequestController
$scope.requests = RequestModel.getRequestsByUser($rootScope.currentUser.userId);  
    if($scope.requests.statusCode == 200) { 
        // do something         
    }
    else if($scope.requests.statusCode == 404) {
        $location.path('/notFound');
    } else if ($scope.requests.statusCode == 500) {
        $location.path('/error');
    }; // PROBLEM: The if/else statement is never true since statusCode is not available
```

Here is my Model:

```
// Inside the RequestModel
this.getRequestsByUser = function(userId) {

    var RequestResource = $resource('../rest/users/' + userId + "/requests");
    var requestList = RequestResource.get({}, function(response, getResponseHeaders) {

        // PROBLEM: The property "stausCode" is "unavilable" at the Controller even if it was set here
        requestList.statusCode = 200;
        console.log("SUCCESS: getRequestsByUser() -> StatusCode: requestList.statusCode");
        console.log(requestList);

    }, function(response, getResponseHeaders) {

        requestList.statusCode = response.status;
        console.log("FAILED: getRequestsByUser() -> StatusCode: " + response.status);

    });
    return requestList;
};
```

This doesn't work since “statusCode” is “unavailable” inside my controller. The REST call works and also the data binding to the view is fine. I’m just not able to implement the “navigation part”. Do I miss something like $watch properties, asynchronous behavior or is my approach just incorrect?!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make better use of resource parameter mapping in your service:

```
// Inside service
this.requestsByUser = $resource('../rest/users/:userId/requests', {userId:'@userId'});
```

That way you'll be able to reuse the same resource for different rest actions (eg. post, delete).

And controller code to handle statuses (response handlers were moved to controller):

```
// Inside the RequestController
$scope.requests = RequestModel.requestsByUser
    .get(
      {userId: $rootScope.currentUser.userId},

      function(response) { // success handler
          if(response.status == 200) {
              // do something         
          }
      },

      function(response) { // error handler
          if(response.status == 404) {
              $location.path('/notFound');
          } else if (response.status == 500) {
              $location.path('/error');
          }
      }
    );
```

Another way around is to use $q service to return promises from your service. But provided solutions seems cleaner to me

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thank you so much! It all works now :) 
I never thought about trying my solution at the wrong place, just about trying it the wrong way…

Comment: You're welcome ,-) And just noticed that better name for requests property regarding changes will be `requestsByUser` without leading `get` - now it allows more